# Can I get Installer for Aperture 3.6?

Tags: photos, aperture

Apple terminated Aperture at 3.6. Photos.app is the only replacement, for my uses it's far from ready. I want to be sure I can run Aperture 3.6 for at least 2 more years. I'd like an installer.

We have been able to download from the app store, but yesterday Apple transiently removed Aperture from our Previous Purchase list. (It's now back.) Aperture 3.4.5 updater is the last version available for downloaded from Apple [1]. No-one I know trusts Apple to keep Aperture available.

Does anyone know a way to get the Aperture 3.6 installer? How about a way to restore Aperture to a new machine from backup?

I have a license of course.

[1] https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1657?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: Why don't you just backup your existing Aperture.app in a safe place?

Comment: I have done that, but I assume the installer does other things. Have you tried installing Aperture by drag and drop of the app backup?

Comment: That's how I restored my Mac after it crashed last summer :-)

Answer (score 3):

I updated from Mavericks to El Captian and suddenly Aperture 3.4.5 stopped working. Sadly, the Aperture 3.6 update is not available in the App store. Don't know if this is a temporary thing or it's gone forever. However, if you have 3.6 on another Mac you can drag the app itself to a flash drive and simply drop it in your App folder. It did it today and it runs perfectly under OS 10.11.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all who contributed.

Apple's plans for the 3.6 updater are unclear -- it was transiently removed but as of Oct 14 it's back again.

The key information is that it seems one can simply backup an installed app and restore it via drag and drop. We don't truly know if everything will work, but it's our best current option.

Comment: John, like you I'm a licensed user pre-app store. Paid $250 CAD. There is no 3.6 updater on Apple's site now. Any chance you could share the 3.6 updater with me?

Comment: John, like you I'm a licensed user pre-app store. Paid $250 CAD. There is no 3.6 updater on Apple's site now. Apple won't move my offline purchase into my app store account (even though it was bought directly from Apple on the same Apple ID email). I'm at my wit's end. Disgusted with Apple.

Comment: Check out this support doc:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201289

Specifically

"If you originally installed Aperture from a DVD"

Dated May 2016.

Comment: Hi John. I'd read that document. It still won't get me Aperture 3.6 from a purchased download version. I've been in touch with Apple Support and they won't help either as I bought from the Canadian app store. Apparently Canadians don't get to keep working Aperture 3.6 - Aperture is not available at all in Canadian app store even for updates. It's so frustrating. Last downloadable updater is 3.4.5. Apple has stolen a $250 software application from me, adding insult to injury (people who bought their pro app for $79 are still able to use it).